# A basis of splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $K$ is the splitting filed of $x^5-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Thus, we know $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, where $\zeta_5=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}.$ Therefore, a basis of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\{1,\zeta_5,\zeta_5^2,\zeta_5^3,\zeta_5^4\}$, right? But since $a+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ is irreducible, we have $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4.$ I don't figure out where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1+\zeta_5+\zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3+\zeta_5^4=\frac{1-\zeta_5^5}{1-\zeta_5}=0$, hence $\{1,\zeta_5,\dots,\zeta_5^4\}$ is linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Removing $\zeta_5^4$ gives you a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $K$.

Comment: Normally, how could I figure out which element is not in a basis?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you remove, but usually people remove $\zeta_5^4$.

Comment: So, in general, in these kind of questions, I should get the dimension first then write down a basis such that the number of elements equals the dimension?

Comment: If you can find the dimension easily, then that's a good way to go.

Comment: OK. But how did have the equation in the very beginning of your answer? I don't get that.

Comment: It's just the sum of a geometric series, together with the fact that $\zeta_5^5=1$.

Comment: Oh! I see, it's a geometric series! Thank you!